# Must Declare the scalar variable "@myTable"

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query here that I want to store the photo image and its history.  I ran into this "Must Declare the scalar variable" message when I am trying to use the @myTable again.  Any ideas for the correct syntax?

```
DECLARE @myTable Table (ID INT, thumbnail varbinary(MAX))

INSERT INTO dbo.Inspection_photo
                (Hea_ID,
                 RowGuid,
                 Photo,
                 EnterBy,
                 EnterDate)
OUTPUT INSERTED.PK_PHOTO, @photo_thumbnail INTO @myTable(ID, thumbnail)
        VALUES (@hea_id,
                NEWID(),
                @photo,
                @enterby,
                @enterdate)

INSERT INTO dbo.Inspection_Photo_Thumbnail
    Select ID, Thumbnail
    From @myTable

INSERT INTO dbo.Inspection_Photo_Hist
            (PK_Photo,
             RowGuid,
             Hea_ID,
             Photo,
             EnterDate,
             EnterBy,
             ModDate,
             ModBy,
             Type)
    Values (@myTable.ID,
            NEWID(),
            @hea_id,
            @photo,
            @enterdate,
            @enterby,
            @enterdate,
            @enterby,
            'INS')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problems is this line.

```
Values (@myTable.ID,
```

You need to use the table `@myTable` in a [FROM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql) clause. Remove the [table valued constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql) and do a [SELECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql) instead.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Inspection_Photo_Hist
            (PK_Photo,
             RowGuid,
             ...
             Type)
SELECT T.ID,
       NEWID(),
       ...
       'INS'
FROM @myTable AS T;
```